# Font Size equal to the height of the current container

Tags: jquery, html, css, font-size

If I have a div that is x high, how can I make the text inside of it the max it can be assuming that it can only take up one line.

While I would prefer a CSS answer, any jquery/javascript answers are accepted just because I need this to work either way :)

Comment: I don't think you can do this easily.  To achieve what you need, you'll have to take the text to be displayed and measure its width in the specific font used by the client.  Then keep decreasing the font size until the width fit inside the width of your container - this will assure that you output it in one line.  Finally, you'll need to take the smaller of the found size or container height - and this is your font size.  As you don't _really_ have control over the font (due to font substitution on the client), you can't achieve this in CSS.  It may be possible in javascript, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on Aleks G's comment, [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/zM9F3/) shows how you would incrementally increase the font size until you'd reached your max:

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <span>This is some text</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
  width: 300px;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;   
}
```

**jQuery**

```
var $span = $('span');
var $div = $('div');

while($span.width() < $div.width()){
    $span.css({fontSize: "+=1"});   
}
$span.css({fontSize: "-=1"});
```

If you wanted to eliminate any stuttering as the font size was being changed, you could hide the text until the `while` loop was complete.

Answer (score 3):

Set the font-size and line-height to the same height of the container:

```
div {
    height:50px;
    font-size:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/V7f4w/

Answer (score 1):

No way I know of to do that with pure CSS that will be cross browser compatibile. Use javascript and/or jquery to do this. I'll write it out in jquery since its a bit easier:

```
$("mydiv").css("font-size", $("mydiv").css("height"));
```